# How do I make an action bar feature from the facebook app?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is a picture of the facebook app from the play store. I would like to copy the part that says "New Stories 10+" in my app. How do I make that? Is that part of the action bar?

I read through the action bar documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) but couldn't find anything about it. I'm having trouble doing a google search for it too because I don't know what it's called.

Also, if you open the facebook app when you're in airplane a very similar type of message comes up that says "No Internet Connection". How is that message created?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking a little more *deeply* at the Facebook app, the bar just appears to be a `LinearLayout` containing two `TextView`s. This layout is then just embedded in the news feed fragment and hidden/shown as needed. In other words, **it's not a part of the action bar**; it's just a normal view within the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this library](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) by Cyril Mottier. it was designed to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this! It's really cool. Can you make the croutons not disappear or be clickable?

Comment: Use the Style.Builder to set properties like duration an such. Check http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/ for some nice tips on how to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is part of the ActionBar but only if the device or emulator is on API 3.0 and higher. if the device or emulator has a lower API level, the actions will appear on the menu button.

This is just a dummy but it will give you a rough idea.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    int groupid = 1;

    menu.add(groupid, 1, 1, "Search").setIcon(R.drawable.embassy_default);
    // menu.add(groupid, , ,"Back").setIcon(R.drawable.hospital_default);
    menu.add(groupid, 1, 1, "Exit").setIcon(R.drawable.government_default);

    return true;

}
```

Read more here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html